# How do you gain treasure from fishing?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know that you can gain treasure from fishing, (Saddles, enchanted books, enchanted bows etc.) but what is the criteria for collecting treasure? Does fishing in a specific biome count? Also, what are the chances of catching treasure (And how much it multiplies with the Luck of the Sea enchantment)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Receiving treasure from fishing has an equal chance in every biome.*

Below is a graph showing the chance of getting treasure with each enchantment stage of Luck Of The Sea:

| Item | None | Stage 1 | Stage 2 | Stage 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Treasure** | **5%** | **7.1%** | **9.2%** | **11.3%** |
| - | - | - | - | - |
| Bow | 0.8% | 1.2% | 1.5% | 1.9% |
| Enchanted Book | 0.8% | 1.2% | 1.5% | 1.9% |
| Fishing Rod | 0.8% | 1.2% | 1.5% | 1.9% |
| Name Tag | 0.8% | 1.2% | 1.5% | 1.9% |
| Nautilus Shell | 0.8% | 1.2% | 1.5% | 1.9% |
| Saddle | 0.8% | 1.2% | 1.5% | 1.9% |

Source: [minecraft.wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fishing#Junk_and_treasure/)